# Looping over a nested structures containing arrays

Tags: coldfusion

I know this question might have many answers, but I have been unable to solve it so far. I want to loop over structures which contain in some fields arrays and within those arrays, additional structures.

I attached a screenshot of the structures.

Currently the problem seems complex and I have not found a solution.

The image is located below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4XPOAJp.png]

Tried this below:

```
<cfloop collection="#qEvents#" item="ii">
<cfoutput>
#ii# - #qEvents[ii]#
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

but got an error at the end like:

Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried.

Comment: Right, Owen... did you research what that error means? You need to finetune your question, which perhaps means giving some more thought to what you're doing. You're looping over a struct which contains arrays. So `qEvents[ii]` is *an array*. You can't simply output an array, can you? Use `<cfdump>` to check intermediary values & from there you should be able to intuit what to do next.  ALso... `ii` is a pretty bloody terrible variable name. It also seems odd that you have a collection called `qEvents` and it's a *struct*. Sounds more like a query or an array to me. What's the struct keyed on?

Comment: Hi adam, If you check the image link which i provided in my question, that will give you a clear idea of what exactly i have in my structure, yes as far as my array is concerned, i know that array is there in a structure and i need to use some kind of **arraycheck** and see if array loop over array and inside that array there is also a structure, so that seems bit complex to me

Comment: That's it, no answer Guys, I am stuck here, seeking advice and help from you, don't solve but at-least guide

Comment: Look at [`isArray()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsArray) and also keep in mind you cannot output an array like you're going to. You have to use `cfdump` or loop through the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what your desired output is, but assuming you are just trying to loop through and display the structure then you can do something like this. Hopefully it'll give you an idea of how to deal with nested structures and you can go from there :)

```
<cfscript>
// example data
qEvents = {
  "attendees" = [{
      "displayName" = "Tom",
      "id" = 1,
      "self" = true
    },{
      "displayName" = "Richard",
      "id" = 2,
      "organizer" = true
    }],
  "creator" = {
    "displayName" = "Harry"
  }
};

// process the data
function showStructure(it) {
  if (IsSimpleValue(it)) {
    return it; // just a simple string
  } else {
    var result = "";
    var isStruct = isStruct(it);
    for (var v in it) {
      if (isStruct) {
        result &= v & " = " & showStructure(it[v]) & chr(10);
      } else { 
        // assuming an array here but could be more complex
        result &= showStructure(v) & chr(10);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>

<cfloop collection="#qEvents#" item="key">
  <cfset keyValue = qEvents[key]>
  <b>#key#</b>:<br>
  #replace(showStructure(keyValue), chr(10), "<br>", "all")#<hr> 
</cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```

Here's an example of it in action on the excellent trycf site: 
http://trycf.com/gist/d71e418802cefe93ae51/acf?theme=monokai

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to inspect each item before you do something with it. `isStruct` and `isArray` is your friend. Once you find a structure, you'll loop its keys, and for an array you'll loop by index and length of array.